# How do I convert a string into a tuple/array in bash?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to add docker images into the Azure container registry.  It requires me to create a bunch of `docker tag` commands like such:

```
>>> docker tag image_id target_name
```

I have the following:

```
>>> docker images | grep confluentinc | grep -v unwanted | awk -F' ' '{print $1, $3}'
```

This prints out:

```
confluentinc/ksqldb-examples c8a9ad1a78d3
confluentinc/cp-server 4323d392ff0a
confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center c2ad89cacb5c
confluentinc/cp-zookeeper eef32dffbb3a
confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server badc5090bcf2
confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-cli aadbff5aa6a1
confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest 60ab197c6938
confluentinc/cp-schema-registry db9f559fd97a
confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center 870dffa09a38
confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka 89ed378bf732
confluentinc/cp-schema-registry f51e4f854dc1
confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest 2632bb34f956
confluentinc/cp-zookeeper 7149731cc563
```

So the idea is to iterate through this output and print for each line:

```
# I'm just showing one line for brevity
>>> docker tag 7149731cc563 someproject.azurecr.io/confluentinc/cp-zookeeper
```

Here's what I have:

```
>>> arr=($(docker images | grep confluentinc | grep -v otsiem | awk -F' ' '{print $1, $3}'))
>>> for item in ${arr[@]}; do tuple=($item); cmd="docker tag $tuple[1] someproject.azurecr.io/$tuple[0]"; echo $cmd; done;
```

Here's the output of the above:

```
    docker tag confluentinc/ksqldb-examples someproject.azurecr.io/
    docker tag c8a9ad1a78d3 someproject.azurecr.io/
    docker tag confluentinc/cp-server someproject.azurecr.io/
    docker tag 4323d392ff0a someproject.azurecr.io/
    docker tag confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center someproject.azurecr.io/
    docker tag c2ad89cacb5c someproject.azurecr.io/
    docker tag confluentinc/cp-zookeeper someproject.azurecr.io/
    docker tag eef32dffbb3a someproject.azurecr.io/
    docker tag confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server someproject.azurecr.io/
    docker tag badc5090bcf2 someproject.azurecr.io/
    docker tag confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-cli someproject.azurecr.io/
    docker tag aadbff5aa6a1 someproject.azurecr.io/
    docker tag confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest someproject.azurecr.io/
    docker tag 60ab197c6938 someproject.azurecr.io/
    docker tag confluentinc/cp-schema-registry someproject.azurecr.io/
    docker tag db9f559fd97a someproject.azurecr.io/
    docker tag confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center someproject.azurecr.io/
    docker tag 870dffa09a38 someproject.azurecr.io/
    docker tag confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka someproject.azurecr.io/
    docker tag 89ed378bf732 someproject.azurecr.io/
    docker tag confluentinc/cp-schema-registry someproject.azurecr.io/
    docker tag f51e4f854dc1 someproject.azurecr.io/
    docker tag confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest someproject.azurecr.io/
    docker tag 2632bb34f956 someproject.azurecr.io/
    docker tag confluentinc/cp-zookeeper someproject.azurecr.io/
    docker tag 7149731cc563 someproject.azurecr.io/
```

My thought process is this:

The first iteration of the for loop I will set the variable `tuple` to be `(confluentinc/ksqldb-examples c8a9ad1a78d3)`.  Then I'll just access the second (`$tuple[1]`) and  first (`$tuple[0]`) element to form the desired output.

However, clearly I'm doing something wrong.

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my bash commands?  How can I achieve my desired output?

Comment: `docker images` has a `--filter` and `--format` options... `$tuple[1]` that's not how you access array, array is accessed with `${tuple[1]}`. And, anyway, `arr=()` splits on spaces already, not on newlines.

Comment: Do you want to *construct* the commands, or *execute* them? Creating and storing shell commands can be troublesome; see [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `read` the input line by line, as usual with a newline separated stream.

```
docker images --format '{{.Repository}} {{.ID}}' | grep confluentinc | grep -v unwante |
while IFS=' ' read -r repo id; do
    docker tag "$repo" "$id"
done
```

Comment: I think the command should be `docker tag "$repo" "someproject.azurecr.io/$id"`.

Comment: I did not know about the `--format` flag.  This is great!  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to append

```
| awk '{print "docker tag " $2 " someproject.azurecr.io/" $1}'
```

Comment: It's weird how I thought about awk at the start but not awk at the end....stupid me.  This is brilliant.